# Images are weirdly croped when sent to the browser

Tags: php, image, header

I'm trying to send an image to the client like this:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {    

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $image = $em->getRepository('AcmeHomeBundle:Image')->find($_SESSION['id']);

        // open the file in a binary mode
        $fpass = fopen($image->getPath(), 'rb');

        header("Content-Type: image/".$image->getFormat());
        header("Content-Length: ".$image->getSize());
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.'.$image->getFormat().'"');

        // dump the picture and stop the script
        fpassthru($fpass);
        exit;
    }
}
```

but the sent image is sometimes cropped. However, the original image is right. Any suggestion of what could be going wrong?

Here is an example:

Original image:

[image: original]

Sent image:

[image: weirdly cropped image]

Comment: Just to be sure...does the code work with that typo corrected?  Line 14:  `$imagen` instead of `$image`.

Comment: @Deryck - Sorry, it is due to my translation to make it more understandable. Edited

Comment: That doesn't look like a crop. That looks like the picture either wasn't sent completely or received completely. What does your network tab tell you?

Comment: @h2ooooooo - Maybe. Any idea?

Comment: Have you used "imageMagick" in PHP?

Comment: @hilarudeens - No. Just GD

Comment: @Manolo Salsas Post your crop code

Comment: @hilarudeens - The crop was unintentional. Any way it is solved. Look below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the picture is only half downloaded or half sent

have a look at the content size is that too small ? Check the output of fpassthru does it match the image size ?

Check there are no errors in the log relating to time or memory

Comment: The size property was not correctly set. That was causing the browser to assume an incorrect file size. Thanks @user1281385.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `header("Content-Length: ".$image->getSize());`. I'd use this property just for this.